# Query webform submissions

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm attempting to perform a query on webform submissions so I can display all submissions submitted by a specific user. However I'm not sure how to make this query. I made a guess that webform submissions were nodes themselves and performed a query like this

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('type', 'webform');
    $nids = $query->execute();
    die(print_r($nids));
```

But it produced no results. Is there a way I can perform a query on webform submissions so that I can select all submissions authored by a specific user?

UPDATE: Looking through the webform module, I did see some code querying submissions.

```
$query = $this->getQuery();
$query->condition('webform_id', $webform->id());
$query->condition('in_draft', FALSE);
$query->range(0, 1);
```

This is exactly the kind of query I want to perform but when I try to use getQuery() I get

> Call to undefined function Drupal\my_module\my_helper_class\getQuery()

I understand how to start entity queries for nodes like this

```
 \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
```

But is there a way to start an entity query without specifying the entity type? Or is there a way to find out what kind of entity type webform queries are?

Comment: You get that error because `getQuery()` is only a method of the class that `$this` is referring to. Could you build a simple view to do this and just feed it a UID argument?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I cannot use a view in this situation since there is a lot more that needs to occur within this module other than just displaying the results.  Displaying the submissions is just a small part of the plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Webform submissions are content entities, so something like this should work:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
    ->condition('uid', $uid)
    ->accessCheck(FALSE);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: This worked! But how did you figure out that webform_submission was the proper entity name?

Comment: It's easy when you know some of the conventions - all entity types live in `Drupal\MODULENAME\Entity`, so I just downloaded the module, looked in src/Entity, found `WebformSubmission`, and checked its ID in the entity type annotation

Comment: Thanks that helps a ton! I'm sure that will help solve a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Would it be possible to user fields aside from id, created, and other base field definitions in a query? For instance if I added 'quantity' as a form field, is there a way I can do ->condition('quantity',5)? or ->sort('quantity','desc') I attempted using that syntax but it did not work.

Comment: Is there way to update an custom field in the webform submission by ~sid~

Comment: Matt, you'd need to query the table directly. See my answer here:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/267306/34673

Answer (score 2):

Remember to include accessCheck(FALSE) or you won't get any result.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
    ->condition('uid', $uid)
    ->accessCheck(FALSE);
$result = $query->execute();
```