# How do I programmatically get the link for a webform submission?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have managed to create a table of webform submissions of a particular type, thanks to the answer from [a question posted here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253669/get-all-submissions-from-specific-webform).  What I would like to do now is add a link for each webform submission, and I can't figure out how.

I tried looking through the API, and found a toUrl function, but I don't understand how to use it to get the link for each webform submission.  Once I have the link, I would like to combine it with the rest of its info in submission_data[] for display in the table.

Thanks in advance!

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
  ->condition('webform_id', 'sign_up');
$result = $query->execute(); // Gives me IDs associated with the "sign_up" webform.

$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
$submissions = $storage->loadMultiple($result);
$submission_data = array();
foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
  $submission_data[] = $submission->getData();
}
// $submission_data now contains all the submissions from "sign_up" webform.
```

How do I add a link to the webform submission? When I look through submission_data[] it doesn't contain the ID of the webform submission

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webform submissions are content entities, you can use any method defined in [\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/interface/EntityInterface) including…

- [$submission->toUrl();](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3AtoUrl)
- [$submission->toLink();](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3AtoLink)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still stuck.  When I try to add $submission->toLink() I get the error 'Drupal\Core\Link could not be converted to string' - how do I get it to print to the page in my table? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try `$submission->toLink()->toRenderable()`

Comment: `$url = $submission->toLink('#' . $submission->id(), 'canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank'],])->toString();`

Comment: `$url = \Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute('#' . $submission->serial(), 'entity.webform.user.submission', ['webform' => $submission->getWebform()->id(), 'webform_submission' => $submission->id()], ['absolute' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])->toString();`

Answer (score 0):

To get this working, I needed to use what jrockowitz suggested in his answer and also add toString() to get it to display properly in the table.

Without toString(), it gave me an error (*Drupal\Core\Link could not be converted to string*), because toUrl() returns an object rather than the url itself)

```
$url = $submission->toUrl()->toString();
```